# jQuery and switch between two cases

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
<a href="#">
<span style="border-right: medium none;" class="Yes">Yes</span>
</a>
<a href="#">
<span class="No">No</span>
</a>
```

if no is `current` I want when click on yes class calling `current` adding on yes span and delete `current` class from no.

If yes `current` I want when click on no class calling `current` adding on no span and delete `current` class from yes.

I want each case happen in just one click.

Comment: How do you determine what's 'current'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample. This is a first cut, may be this can be optimized. All I am trying to do is remove `current` class from all the elements and add it to current one.

You have to modify your html to have a unique class

```
    <a href="#">
    <span style="border-right: medium none;" class="Yes yesno">Yes</span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <span class="No yesno">No</span>
</a>
```

This is the jQuery code

```
        $('.yesno').click(function(){
            $('.yesno').each(function(i, v){
                $(v).removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });
```

see if it helps..

Comment: I don't understand the `$('.yesno').each(function(i, v){ $(v).removeClass('current'); });`  Why not `$('.yesno').removeClass('current');` ?

Comment: @Nick Craver, Yes it can be done directly with out a loop, I started doing something else and was left like that. I also mentioned in the post that this can be optimized further.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".Yes, .No").click(function() {
  if(!$(this).hasClass("current"))
    $(".Yes, .No").toggleClass("current");
});
```

`Yes` and `No` both fire the click, but the action only happens if the click didn't happen on the current one.  Just set current to whatever you want initially, the toggle will take care of it from then on as you describe in the question.

Comment: Clever solution, but what happens if both of them doesn't have a class `current` initially?

Comment: @Teja - I assume based on the question one would initially.  If you read the text of the question, in each action case it should only happen if the *other* element has the `current` class.  If you can't do it server side, then you could default to no on everything like this: `$(".No").addClass("current");`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am misinterpreting your question, but it looks like you're trying to produce something that behaves like Radio Buttons.

```
<div class="radioButtons">
    <a href="#">Yes</a>
    <a href="#">No</a>
    <a href="#">Maybe</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function select(event) {
        var clicked = $(event.target);
        clicked.siblings('a').removeClass('selected');
        clicked.addClass('selected');
    }

    $(function() {
        $('.radioButtons a').click(select);
    });
</script>
```