# problem with jquery each and swich between 2 things

Tags: jquery

[first see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435547/jquery-and-swich-between-two-cases-problem)
i got this code

```
$('.yesno').click(function(){
    $('.yesno').each(function(i, v){
        $(v).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $(this).addClass('selected');

     return false;
});
```

and html this

```
    <a href="#">
    <span  class="Yes yesno">Yes</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <span class="No yesno">No</span>
```

no the problem when i make more than one vote iam get very big problem

see this

```
<a href="#">
    <span  class="Yes yesno">Yes</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <span class="No yesno">No</span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <span  class="Yes yesno">Yes</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <span class="No yesno">No</span>
</a>
</a>
```

when click first yes it make it selected and when iam going to the next yes when click its because `selected` but the first yes became `unselected`

i want make some thin make each yes and know is differant of others

Answer (score 3):

Change your html to this (Added divs around groups of links, could be any element, or you could do it with a rel attribute on the href too).

```
<div class="linkgroup">  
  <a href="#">
      <span  class="Yes yesno">Yes</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
      <span class="No yesno">No</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="linkgroup">  
  <a href="#">
      <span  class="Yes yesno">Yes</span>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
      <span class="No yesno">No</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Then JS something like:

```
$('.yesno').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.linkgroup').find('.yesno').each(function(i, v){
        $(v).removeClass('selected');
    });
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

(There's also a sibling selector for jquery, which may make the code a bit cleaner, but not familiar with it).

Comment: this is really efficiency solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yesno').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.linkgroup').find('.yesno').each(function(i, v){
        $(v).toggleClass('selected');
    });
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```